# Monotonicity of quotient function from the monotonicity of original functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let,
$h,g:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be two continuous and increasing functions such that,
$\frac{h(t)}{g(t)} \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.

From this can we show that near 0,  $\frac{h(t)}{g(t)}$ is increasing?

I need this because while reading about Hausdorff dimension, there is a generalized definition where Dimension function is used to define Hausdorff dimension. Above mentioned $h,g$ are such functions. There it is written that if $h,g$ satisfies the above mentioned conditions and $\mathcal{H}^g(F)<\infty$ then $\mathcal{H}^h(F)=0$, where $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now if ${U_i}$ is a $\delta$ cover of $F$ then, if it can be shown that $h/g$ is increasing near zero then

$h(|U_i|)=\frac{h(|U_i|)}{g(|U_i|)}g(|U_i|)\leq \frac{h(\delta)}{g(\delta)}g(|U_i|)$

And now raising both sides to a power $s\geq0$ and summing and then taking limit as $\delta \rightarrow 0$, We can get the desired result. This was my plan. But without that monotonicity of $h/g$ the proof will be incomplete.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you don't get that quotient to be increasing, however that's not an issue for what you want. In order to bound the quantities $h(|U_i|)/g(|U_i|)$, use the following fact:

If $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\lim_{t\to0} f(t)=0$, then the function $F(t):= \sup_{s\in (0,t)} |f(s)|$ satisfies $\lim_{t\to 0}F(t)=0$.

This sort of "self-improvement" of the limit condition is immediate once you unpack the $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ definition of limit.

Now just apply this with $f(t)=h(t)/g(t)$ to get the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that $f(x):=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$ oscillates such that at $x=\frac1n$, $f(x)=x$ if $n$ is odd and $f(x)=2x$ if $n$ is even. To achieve this, simply let (alternatingly) one of $g,h$ be constant on $[\frac 1{n+1},\frac 1n]$ and let the other grow by a factor of $2$

Comment: Then h/g becomes discontinuous, but as h and g both are continuous in the first place, h/g has to be continuous.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.